# How to set img size as percentage of parent element within sizes attribute

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set the size of an image as a percentage of its parent element within the srcset/sizes attributes? I have only seen ways to set the size as an absolute or as a percentage of the view port.

If the above is not possible, and we are using relative img widths in say, a grid, is there a way (in CSS and/or HTML) to tell the browser to download different img resolutions depending on the device size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the image width a percentage it will shrink the image to the width of the parent element I think.

```
height: auto;
width: 40%;
```

If you want to use different resolutions you can use the @ media rule. Set up an empty div where the image should go. Then use the @ media rule to change the background image at different screen widths in CSS.

In your html where the image should go:

```
<div class="yourclass"></div>
```

In your  css document:

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 630px) {
     .yourclass {
     background-image: url("yourpciture.png");
    }
    }
```

If you create one of these for each resolution change you want the image will change when someone drags their window or when you change devices. Just remember it's min width so call them smallest screen size to largest or your changes will be overridden.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I guess the sizes attribute doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the size attribute only effects the width of input tags.